# Stress tensor decomposition and names for different components

Tags: terminology, stress-strain

The stress tensor can be decomposed into a spherical component (which is a scalar multiple of the identity tensor) and a deviatoric component which is the original tensor with the spherical component subtracted out.

My question is about the different names for these components. I want to make sure I have them all straight.

The spherical component is sometimes called the "hydrostatic" stress.
The spherical component is sometimes called the "octahedral normal stress".
The deviatoric component is sometimes called the "deviator" stress.
The deviatoric component is sometimes called the "octahedral shear stress".

The spherical component is sometimes called the "mean" stress. This one I am particularly unsure on. Is the mean stress the spherical component but only in the principal orientation?  Or is mean stress just an alternative name for the spherical component?

A few more details I've determine in the past few hours. The octahedral normal stress is the single independent scalar component of the spherical component of the stress tensor. It does not appear to be equal to the norm of the spherical component. The octahedral normal stress is also called the *mean* stress or *hydrostatic* stress.

If anyone knows better or believes I have any of this wrong so far please set me straight.